# Lapply for multiple elements within in list R (maybe loop?)

Tags: r, lapply

I have the following code which extracts tables from 9 pdf documents and produces a list with 9 elements.

```
library(tabulizer)

files <- dir(path = ".", pattern = "\\.pdf$", full.names = TRUE, recursive = TRUE)
mdata <- list()

All <- lapply(files,function(i){extract_tables(i, header=TRUE)
})
```

I then can get the data from the first element (which is also the first pdf) using this code and extarct the data I want:

```
col_names_list <- lapply(All[[1]], function(x) x[1,]) # we extract the first row (colnames)
 data1 <- lapply(All[[1]], function(x) as.matrix(x[-1, ]))
 data2 <- map2(All[[1]], col_names_list, function(x,y) {colnames(x)[0] <- y[0] 
 x})
searchterms <-c('malaria')#, 'cases')
pattern <- paste(searchterms, collapse = "|")

All[[1]] %>% 
map(function(x) x[grepl(pattern, x[,1], ignore.case = TRUE),, drop =   FALSE])-> df2
```

I can repalce the `All[[1]` to `All[[2]]` manually and run the code on the second element. How can I automate this so the code is applied to all 9 elements. Currently it only runs the code on the first element of the list. Without `[[]]` this I get the warning: `Error in x[1, ] : incorrect number of dimensions`.

Comment: I would need data to verify but if you have nine elements and want to replace `All[[1]]` - with all of the iterations you can wrap your `lapply` with another `lapply` maybe like this: `lapply(1:9, function(x){col_names_list <- lapply(All[[x]]...)})`

Comment: I get a subscipt out of bound error when I try this.

Comment: Is there any way you can share some data so I can reproduce this?

Comment: Here are the files I am using, I think you could run the whole scipt and it should extract all the data I am using.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/13ef_7quih6YgLhOFgYLCOBWO2G3VOlY3/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1g7-FEOXumkcPUeIXSg9QV1Oy3tL8bTA8/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HJlhloSj8a9QpmZkWiAQvlAXo3r8m19V/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1l5EOLrlyHy2k4x6uxj8KyYk30MYcwFVJ/view?usp=sharing